# Rails application performance enhancement doubt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, performance, caching, optimization

I am developing an application in Rails in which I have a table that contains static data which will mostly be read-only and will be updated **very very** rarely.

But a same query will be executed several times on the table (the query does not involve any other table).

To avoid redoing this work, is it advisable to implement some cache mechanism through code??

If so, what is the best technique to implement that?

I am planning to have a GLOBAL hash variable with the primary key as the hash key and the value as the result of the query.

1. Are there any drawbacks of this technique???
2. One thing that I can see is that when the table is updated, the server needs to be restarted.
3. Is there a nicer way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you redo something which exist and works perfectly.
2. Well, can't see why you think that
3. Of course, yes:

Your choices are more or less:

- built-in: `memory store`
- requiring some setup: `memcached`
- alternative key/value storage: `redis` http://redis.io/

Have a look here: http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails

Comment: Memcached it is!!! I have heard about it so many times but really did not take effort to know wat it is :(. Thanks for your update. Also thanks for editing my original post. It now looks a lot clearer. Will put things this way from next time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Rails.cache` - when you need to refresh the cache, just expire the keys?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest for dynamic data is to use Rails's own fragment caching.  To expire use a sweeper which is an observer that is called when your model changes and will expire the cache.  [See the Rails guide on caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) for help on Fragment Caching and Sweepers.

The only thing the guide doesn't cover is pretty obvious, that you need to use the globally keyed fragment **and** include your record's ID in the key string.  Like: `<% cache( "foo_stuff_#{@foo.id}" ) do %>`